# TextView height changing automatically with different text in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/bneg"
        android:text="-"
        android:background="#ff3333"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsub"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#aaaaff"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="back"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
```

When I use "back" in button text its height become small and when I use only text "b" background height remains same. Why this happening? and what would be the solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please set height according to ba. set text ba then give whatever height you requires then change text to b and see if it is working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the text *back* then you should make the width `wrap_content`instead of a fixed width. Or if you do need a fixed width and height then just use smaller text.